# Does binary extension field multiplication matrix have random rows?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

Any element in a boolean extension field $a\in GF(2^n)$ can be presented by a boolean vector $a_{(2)} \in GF(2)^n$.  For any element $a\in GF(2^n)$, there exists a boolean matrix $M_a\in GF(2)^{n\times n}$ such that $(ab)_{(2)} = M_a \cdot (b)_{(2)}$.

**The question:**
For any non-zero $\vec v\in GF(2)^n$,
is the mapping $a\mapsto \vec v^T M_a$ a bijection?
In other words, if $a\in GF(2^n)$ is a uniform random field element, is $\vec v^T M_a$ uniform random as well?

Note that, the mapping $a \mapsto M_a \vec v$ is a bijection for any non-zero $\vec v\in GF(2)^n$.
Because there exists non-zero $v\in GF(2^n)$ that $v_{(2)} = \vec v$,
then $M_a \vec v = M_a \cdot v_{(2)} = (av)_{(2)}$.
In other words, if $a$ if random,
so every column vector in $M_a$ is random, every linear combination of column vectors in $M_a$ is random.  I wonder if the same holds for its row vectors.

Comment: What is the meaning of random here?

Comment: @DieterKadelka uniform random.

Comment: So in other words you're asking whether $\vec v \to \vec v^T M_a$ is a bijection?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I wonder whether $a \mapsto \vec v^T M_a$ is a bijection, for any non-zero $\vec v$.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks for the comment.  I guess bijection is a much better language here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $a \mapsto M_a$ is a linear transformation from $GF(2)^n$ to $GF(2)^{n \times n}$, so $a \mapsto \vec{v}^{T} M_a$ is a linear transformation from $GF(2)^n$ to the dual vector space $(GF(2)^n)^*$. Both of these vector spaces are $n$-dimensional. To see that the linear transformation $a \mapsto \vec{v}^{T} M_a$ is a bijection, we will show that its kernel is zero-dimensional, i.e. the only $a \in GF(2)^n$ such that $\vec{v}^{T} M_a=0$ is $a=0$.

By assumption $\vec{v} \neq 0$, so there exists $\vec{w} \in GF(2)^n$ such that $\vec{v}^{T} \vec{w} \neq 0$. Let $b \in GF(2^n)$ be the field element such that $b_{(2)} = \vec{w}$. If $a \neq 0$, we may define $c = a^{-1} b \in GF(2^n)$ and $\vec{x} = c_{(2)} \in GF(2)^n$. Then we have $M_a \vec{x} = (a c)_{(2)} = (a a^{-1} b)_{(2)} = b_{(2)} = \vec{w}$ so $\vec{v}^{T} M_a \vec{x} = \vec{v}^{T} \vec{w} \neq 0$. Hence, when $a \neq 0$ it follows that $\vec{v}^{T} M_a \neq 0$, so there are no non-zero vectors in the kernel of the linear transformation $a \mapsto \vec{v}^{T} M_a$, as claimed.

Comment: Thanks for the neat proof!  Pls let me acknowledge you if this becomes part of my paper.

Comment: Happy to help! If you make use of this proof in a paper please feel free to acknowledge me.